# Detect click outside of the current web component

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer, web-component

I have a web component (Polymer 3) that is embedded in other components and want to "sense" clicks outside of it. For example, in React I would do something like this inside of the component:

```
document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside, true);

 public handleClickOutside = event => {
        const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

        if (!domNode || !domNode.contains(event.target)) {
           //logic
        }
    }
```

Above we simply add a click event, and then check if the event have targeted the current component via a reference.

As its "react syntax" I need to to something similar but for web components. I need a reference to the current web component. I have tried:

```
 const domNode = this;
```

And

```
const domNode = this.$['my-component'];
```

without luck. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you couldn't. I do something like it, some time ago.

You could listen when a click is done in the rest of dom and act. Use `:not` css selector, or just, simply, listen all clicks and compare:

```
//listen clicks
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){   
  //check if click was outside of #myObject
  if !(document.getElementById('myObject').contains(event.target)){
    //Only if click outside...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

LOL, *"Let's query the whole (virtual)DOM"*
and they still claim React is fast?

**Reverse** your logic, detect clicks ***inside*** your component.

It is 2021, we no longer support IE

[Event.composedPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) gives you all DOM nodes the `click` Event passed.

And **do** read the `focusout` Event and `:focus-within` CSS answers
at: [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element/67036853#67036853)

I added some nested shadowDOMs to show `composedPath` gives you all DOM nodes.

Remember: [CustomEvents](https://javascript.info/dispatch-events) need `composed:true` as option setting, for the Event to *escape* shadowDOM.
Native Events like `click` always escape shadowDOM

And remember... React **never** supported the native Event model.
https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/libraries/react/results/results.html
You have to write a React wrapper **for each and every native Web Component**
That is like buying a can of soup, and always having to buy a canopener with it.

```html
<style>
  body { cursor:pointer }
  ::part(shadowdiv) { /* modern CSS shadowParts to style 'parts' inside shadowDOM */
    color: white;
    font: 14px Arial;
    width: 80%;
  }
</style>

<custom-element></custom-element>

<script>
  window.CEdepth = 0;
  window.addEventListener("click",e=>console.clear());
  customElements.define("custom-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:'open'});
      if (window.CEdepth++ < 3) {
        this.id = window.CEdepth;
        window.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
          let inside = evt.composedPath().includes(this);
          console.log("clicked inside #"+this.id, ":", inside);
        });
        this.style.display = "inline-block";
        this.style.padding = "1em";
        this.style.background = ["red", "blue", "green"][this.id - 1];
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<div part='shadowdiv'>Web Component #${this.id}`
                                   +`<custom-element><b/></custom-element><div/>`;
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```